# what countrows().equals() means in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I can't understand the structure of the written code

```
(CountRows("client_code").Equals(Parameters!client_code.Count)
```

can anyone explain this please?

And where can I find a reference for all the functions that I can use to write Expression in SSRS??

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS we use "=" operator for comparison rather than equals.
Expression mentioned by you below

```
 (CountRows("client_code").Equals(Parameters!client_code.Count)
```

Rather it should be like

```
=IIF(CountRows("client_code")=Parameters!client_code.Count,true,false)
```

What your mentioned code does: It Returns a count of rows within the specified scope, Scope can be Group as well. and it compared with your Report Parameter count.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) you will find complete list of functions and expression for SSRS.

Comment: You can't use `=` in an expression like that.  If there was an `IIF` statement, it would work, but as it is now, that expression won't work.

Comment: True, Thanks for pointing it out. I meant the same for IIF statement, Edited my answer.